# Liquibase to insert multiple rows using valueComputed

Tags: liquibase

```
    <changeSet author="tarun" id="122">
        <insert tableName="table1">
            <column name="uuid" valueComputed="SELECT uuid  from table2 group by  uuid" />   
        </insert>
      </changeSet>
```

SELECT uuid  from table2 group by  uuid is returning 3 rows .

Comment: what error do you get after trying out the above changeset?

Comment: I am getting 

syntax error at or near "SELECT"
  Position: 42 [Failed SQL: INSERT INTO public.table1 (uuid) VALUES  (SELECT uuid  from table2 group by  uuid)

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the syntax error because the `valueComputed` attribute adds `VALUES` inside the `INSERT` query. So for example, the resultant query looks like this `INSERT INTO public.table1 (uuid) VALUES (SELECT uuid from table2 group by uuid)` which if you directly try running on DB will result into an error.
While using sub queries inside INSERT statement, we do not need to use `VALUES` there.

Can you try it with using SQL tag inside XML changeset as below:

```
<changeSet author="tarun" id="122">
  <sql>
    INSERT INTO public.table1 (uuid) SELECT uuid from table2 group by uuid
  </sql>
  <rollback>
    ***Rollback query for above SQL goes here***
  </rollback>
</changeSet>
```

This will result in the same output that you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Earlier I was using sql tag and it worked fine, but there is requirement to use only liquibase tag.